# Autocompletion and automatically adding imports in FXML?

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, javafx-2, fxml

I am using Eclipse for editing/creating .fxml files. What I am missing here are automatic imports ("organize imports") and auto completion while typing. How to add these features to Eclipse? Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 0):

Go to eclipse market place from the help menu at the top and search for javafx.  In the results should be e(fx)clipse, download.

You might want to take a back-up of your eclipse directory (the one with exe's and plugins, not the workspace) in case there is a problem during install.

Comment: e(fx)clipse does not give you the possibility to organize fxml imports.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand not possible so far.
See here:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=444927

If you have e(fx)clipse plugin installed, you can open SceneBuilder from within Eclipse, which will let you to organize imports.

[image]